# Trouble with contextual action mode and onClickListener

Tags: android, onclick, contextual-action-bar

I'm trying to create an activity for managing different paths. On the left side there should be a sidebar where you can select different courses. On the right side the corresponding pathattributes shall be displayed.

When I long click on an item then the contextual action mode should be started. There you can select multiple items and can perform some batch operations like update more entrys at once or delete them from the list.

The problem is, whenever I change the orientation of the emulator or a real device while being in the action mode, the app crashes. I tried different way to finish the mode ( mode.finish, with Boolean values at onSaveInstances ...) but the mode always restore at onCreate.

Another strange behavior refers to the PathSimpleCurosrAdapter. This is an ordenary SimpleCursorAdapter which edits the ListView children depending on their underlying data and colors the first child lightgrey.
Without the MulitChoiceListener everything works fine but with it I can't change the color of the first element by my normal onItemClickfunction.

My MainActivity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private int current_clicked=0; // marks last clicked item at lv_pahtlist
    private ListView lv_pathlist;
    private ListView lv_pathdetail;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private boolean isInActionMode;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       lv_pathlist =(ListView) findViewById (R.id.listview_main);
       lv_pathdetail=(ListView) findViewById (R.id.listview_path);

       // SQLHelper creates or retrieves database
       DBZugriff dbhelp=new DBZugriff(this, "Pfaddetails");
       db=dbhelp.getWritableDatabase();

       Cursor Cursor=db.query("ta_pathlist", new String[]{"pathname, refresh, saved", "_id"},
               "", null, null, null, null); 
       PathSimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new PathSimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
               R.layout.list_item_img1, Cursor, new String[]{"pathname"}, new int[]{R.id.item_tv_path_detail},0);
       lv_pathlist.setAdapter(adapter);
       lv_pathlist.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

       Cursor cursor2=db.query("ta_pathattribute", new String[]{"_id","attribute_value"},
               "fk_path=1", null, null, null, null); 
       SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),
               R.layout.list_item2, cursor2, new String[]{"attribute_value"}, new int[]{R.id.list_item2_tv},0);
       lv_pathdetail.setAdapter(adapter2);


       //Contextmenu
       registerForContextMenu(lv_pathlist);
       lv_pathlist.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
       lv_pathlist.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

          public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                                                 long id, boolean checked) {
                if (checked==true)
                    lv_pathlist.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                else
                    lv_pathlist.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
           }


           public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
               MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
               inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_context, menu); 
               return true;
           }

           public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                   for(int i=0; i<lv_pathlist.getCount();i++)
                       lv_pathlist.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                   //if possible: mark last clicked element
                   if(lv_pathlist.getChildAt(current_clicked)!=null)
                       lv_pathlist.getChildAt(current_clicked).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
           }


           public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
               for (int i=0;i<lv_pathlist.getCount();i++)
                   lv_pathlist.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
               SparseBooleanArray checked= lv_pathlist.getCheckedItemPositions();
               for(int index = checked.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--)
                   lv_pathlist.getChildAt(index).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
               return false;
           }


           public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode arg0, MenuItem arg1) {
               //Some actions
               return false;
           }
       });

       // change background color when item is checked/unchecked
       lv_pathlist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           //@Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

               lv_pathlist.getChildAt(current_clicked).setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
               lv_pathlist.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
               current_clicked=position;
           }
       });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

PathSimpleCursorAdapter

```
    public class PathSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{


    public PathSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView (View view, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        /*
         * Der größte Teil der Arbeit wird von der Vatermethode erledigt
         */
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);


        if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("saved"))==1)
            view.findViewById(R.id.item_img_path_detail1).setVisibility(0);
        if(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("refresh"))==1)
            view.findViewById(R.id.item_img_path_detail2).setVisibility(0);

    }
    }
```

The activity layout

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listview_main"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"    
        >   
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_right"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Main_Image"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:maxHeight="120dp"
            android:maxWidth="120dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/Button"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Button"/>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_path"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="50dp"
            android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent">
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

The item layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/item_tv_path_detail"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_img_path_detail1"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/content_attachment"
        android:visibility="invisible"
  />
        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_img_path_detail2"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_refresh"
        android:visibility="invisible"
  />


  </LinearLayout>
```

the logcat says

```
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.hsanhalt.inf.treeducation/de.hsanhalt.inf.treeducation.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3351)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:123)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1151)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at de.hsanhalt.inf.treeducation.MainActivity$1.onPrepareActionMode(MainActivity.java:126)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.widget.AbsListView$MultiChoiceModeWrapper.onPrepareActionMode(AbsListView.java:5644)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView$ActionModeCallbackWrapper.onPrepareActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2469)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$ActionModeImpl.invalidate(ActionBarImpl.java:699)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.startActionMode(ActionBarImpl.java:394)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.Activity.onWindowStartingActionMode(Activity.java:4380)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionMode(PhoneWindow.java:2171)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.startActionModeForChild(PhoneWindow.java:2158)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.view.ViewGroup.startActionModeForChild(ViewGroup.java:571)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.view.View.startActionMode(View.java:3607)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onRestoreInstanceState(AbsListView.java:1622)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:9939)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchThawSelfOnly(ViewGroup.java:2338)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(AdapterView.java:778)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2324)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2324)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:9917)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1600)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:906)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:878)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1100)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
11-26 20:23:49.685: E/AndroidRuntime(638):  ... 12 more
```

Comment: Post your logcat please.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it seems like this  `lv_pathlist.getCheckedItemPositions()` returns `null`, and you then immediately call `.size()`. Can you add a null check and see if it stops failing? If it stops failing it probably means that the checked states are not being preserved properly.

Comment: Thanks, this seemed to be the trick for this issue. But is there a way how I can disable the mode when I turn the device or alternatively get my simplecursoradapter to work? I still have the impression that the MultiChoiceListener and onItemClickListener are kind of working against each other. Like I said - without the CAB stuff everything works perfectly fine.

Comment: Quite honestly I'm not as familiar with the multi-choice mode, but my hunch is that you need to save the selected items in `onSaveInstanceState()` then restore those as soon as you set the adapter after the restart. That should set everything up correctly.